# Recurring payment using reference transaction

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Is it possible to Create a Recurring Payment Profile using `DoReferenceTransaction` or is there any other way to set up recurring payment when I've got "billing agree" from customer and `REFERENCEID` - an id of customer's previous transaction.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
RECURRING
```

field of DoReferenceTransaction API call, but first you need a billing agreement with buyer.

I recommend doing recurring payment with CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call.

API is [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/createrecurringpaymentsprofile-api-operation-nvp).

Answer (score 0):

I've got billing agreement with buyer ("billing agreement ID") - according to [reference transaction api](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns) .

I also can do transactions with DoReferenceTransaction like:

```
$nvpstr="&L_AMT0=".$itemamt."&L_QTY0=1&AMT=".(string)$amt."&ITEMAMT=".(string)$itemamt."&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&REFERENCEID=B-6J7244599E964634T&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL ."&CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyCodeType."&PAYMENTACTION=".$paymentType;

$resArray=hash_call("DoReferenceTransaction",$nvpstr);
```

However I still don't know how to set up recurring payment using reference transaction cause in API link you gave me, there is a note that `Credit Card ACCT number` is required - but I don't want to store client's card numbers in my database (I am using express checkout).